# What is the closest equivalent in JSR 303 for @ScriptAssert?

Tags: jakarta-ee, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

There is an excellent `@ScriptAssert` in Hibernate validator which makes cross field validation very easy.

In Java EE, JSR-303 borrowed almost everything from Hibernate validator, but it does not seem to have borrowed `@ScriptAssert` (yet).

What is the closest equivalent in JSR 303 for `@ScriptAssert`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent constraint defined by the Bean Validation specification itself. If you don't want to depend on `@ScriptAssert` for portability reasons, your best choice would be create your own custom script-based constraint.

Answer (score 4):

If you’re using Spring Framework, then you can use validator based on Spring Expression Language (SpEL) instead of `@ScriptValidator` — [validator-spring](https://github.com/jirutka/validator-spring). It’s a tiny library that depends just on `validation-api` and `spring-expression`.